# Convert YAML file to Application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, converters, properties-file, application.properties

For Spring Boot, how can we convert `application.yaml` to `application.properties`?

```yaml
pay.payment:
  sandbox:
    Url: https://securegw-stage//processTransaction
      callbackUrl: http://localhost:8080/pgresponse
      details:
        CHANNEL_ID: '${pay.payment.sandbox.channelid}'
        INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID: '${pay.payment.sandbox.industrytypeid}'
        CALLBACK_URL: '${pay.payment.sandbox.callbackUrl}'
```

Is there any tool to convert YAML to app.properties online?

Comment: The format is called YAML and the recommended file extension for those files has beeen `.yaml` since 2006.

Answer (score 5):

I dealt with the same problem using a [python script](https://github.com/up2code/yaml2props/blob/master/yaml2props.py).

Just clone and run:

```
$ python yaml2props.py {your_path_file}
```

**Note**

In my specific case on Ubuntu 18.04, I had to install *pyperclip* library and use python3, so:

```
$ pip3 install pyperclip
$ python3 yaml2props.py {your_path_file}
```

Comment: Reginaldo, does it support lists?

Comment: Here's the example: https://rollout.io/blog/yaml-tutorial-everything-you-need-get-started/

Comment: Hi @ATrubka, I've just tested it with your example and it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

The `yml` is a tree, to convert to a properties you just need the extra boilerplate of the preceding hierarchy e.g.

```
pay.payment.sandbox.url=https://securegw-stage//processTransaction
pay.payment.sandbox.callbackurl=http://localhost:8080/pgresponse
pay.payment.sandbox.details.CHANNEL_ID='${pay.payment.sandbox.channelid}'
pay.payment.sandbox.details.INDUTRY_TYPE_ID='${pay.payment.sandbox.industrytypeid}'
pay.payment.sandbox.details.CALLBACK_URL='${pay.payment.sandbox.callbackUrl}'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ,Btw can you tel me difference between pay.payment.sandbox.callbackurl=http://localhost:8080/pgresponse   pay.payment.sandbox.details.CALLBACK_URL='${pay.payment.sandbox.callbackUrl}'

Comment: that's a placeholder, it will be expanded  to the `callbackUrl` value. Wrapped in `'` I think